# Downloadable product link does not work for customer after purchase

Tags: products-management, downloadable

I created a downloadable product type in magento 1.7, successfully and uploaded the files using filezilla to the media/downloadable/folder. The product is an e-book or flip book that the customer is supposed to read from their account.
I did a test purchase the purchase is successful, a download link goes to the customer's account, but nothing happens.
The url I used in the downloadable configuration was: `http://sitename/media/downloadable/filename/index.html`
I've searched all over for solutions and you were the closest I found.
After reading a post here I created  files/links/first_letter of filename/second letter of filename and placed the product accordingly. Still no success. I even ran the magento check on the host site.
I am literally stumped now...what am I missing?

Comment: What URL is the customer receiving?

Answer (score 2):

You can upload your product(e-book or flip book) directly at the back-end(admin) side from the Downloadable Information tab in Catalog->Manage products section. And it will be available for download after purchase it by any customer in their account on your store.

It may help you to solve your your problem.